# asp.net razor allow edit page only for logged in user

Tags: asp.net, razor

I have this profile edit page, but if the user changes id in the url he can change other users profile, how do i deny access to other id's in url

```
 if (!IsPost)
    {
        //if(!Request.QueryString["ID"].IsEmpty()){
        if (!Request.QueryString["UserId"].IsEmpty() && Request.QueryString["UserId"].IsInt())

        {
            UserId = Request.QueryString["UserId"];
            var db = Database.Open("mystring");
            var dbCommand = "SELECT * FROM UserProfile WHERE UserId = @0";
            var row = db.QuerySingle(dbCommand, UserId);

            if (row != null)
            {
                Email = row.Email;
                fullname = row.fullname;
                location = row.location;

            }
            else
            {

                ModelState.AddFormError("No Profile was selected.");


            }
```

Comment: what kind of authentication are you using?

Comment: try solution proposed by Darin Dimitrov, you shouldn't get user id from query string without any checking

Answer (score 0):

By not allowing to pass the userid as query string parameter but read it from the encrypted Forms Authentication cookie.

So:

```
var UserId = Request.QueryString["UserId"];
```

should become:

```
string username = User.Identity.Name;
```

This will give you the currently authenticated username and then change only his profile.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it.

1. Do not pass User Id as Query String. Pass it in model object
2. If you decided to pass user id from query string and if you have authentication set in place then you could match the user id passed in query string with user id of logged in user. If these two match, then only allow edit